# How to manage shared UI state in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

According to the Jetpack Compose guidelines, every screen should have its own UI state with its own viewModel*

[image: UI data flow]

Let's say I have a wizard type of screens, where the user enters data on screen A, B, C and gets to the review screen on Screen D. Note that, all this is locally entered and managed data. So, no data layer is required for any pages except ScreenD..

All the screen's viewModel will look like:

```
data class Screen{X}UiState(
    myString: String?
)

class Screen{X}ViewModel: ViewModel() {
     private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(Screen{X}UiState())
     val uiState = _uiState.toStateFlow()

     fun mySetterMethod(myValue: String?) {
           _uiState.update { itCopy(myString = myValue) }
     }
}
```

When i get to the Screen D, I need to display all the values entered from Screen A, B and C. Technically, i'd expect the shared state hoisted to the NavHost -- the lowest common ancestor. This means in addition to updating my current Screen state in `mySetterMethod`, I'd have to pass the updated state to the Navhost too. Is my understanding right?

```
NavHost(
        startDestination = "ScreenA"
) {
        val screenDUiState = MutableStateFlow(ScreenDUiState())
        composable(route = "ScreenA") {
            ScreenA()
        }
        composable(route = "ScreenB") {
            ScreenB()
        }
        composable(route = "ScreenC") {
            ScreenC()
        }
        composable(route = "ScreenD") {
            ScreenD(screenDUiState)
        }
}
```

- https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer#define-ui-state

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right, in order to share and reuse the data from those 4 screens you would need to hoist the state (the lowest common ancestor is not a *must* but it does simplify things a lot), so in your scenario you can either:

1. hoist it to the navigation (as you did)
2. use a shared view model
3. use compose navigation [with arguments](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-with-args)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's generally the norm to have one VM per screen, but this might be a good use case to use a single VM for the complete flow.

One view model, one state class, update the relevant properties of the state object on each particular screen, all of the state properties are then available to the summary screen.

It would simplify the implementation as is, and would also make it easier to jump back to any step in the flow (since you already have the same VM with the state persisted). Also if you wanted to add tablet support later with a single screen (utilising all the additional space) you could also use the same VM, same business logic and avoid duplication.

The libraries have always supported this kind of behaviour, as has Dagger/Hilt, including it's compose library.